# How to create a generic three dimentional collection in .NET

Tags: .net, generics, collections, generic-collections

I am trying to create or use a framework object that behaves like a dictionary, but has two key values to determine a third. Is there a built in three dimension collection in .NET?

simple example:
I need to present a table that has, per student and class, the final grade.

Comment: what about collection of collection of collection?

Comment: Just nest dictionaries, like `Dictionary<Student, Dictionary<Course, int>>`

Comment: I was trying to avoid the nested collections... I recall being able to create any number of dimensions on an array on C++, I was hoping for something similar to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<clsStudent, Dictionary<clsClass,clsGrade>> dic = new Dictionary<clsStudent, Dictionary<clsClass,clsGrade>>();
```

Comment: Dictionary<clsStudent, Dictionary<clsClass,clsGrade>> dic = new Dictionary<clsStudent,Dictionary<clsClass,clsGrade>>();